# How to open multiple pop-up windows?

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow

I have five links and each links to a page.

```
function TohokuImgPopup(url) { 
popupWindow = window.open(
                    url, 'popUpWindow'+randomno, 'height=246,width=228,left=0,top=0,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no')
            }
```

This is the function I am using. I have different function for the 5 links, each opens a new window. But I am only able to open one popup at a time. How can I open multiple popups?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(


function a1(url) { 
popupWindow1 = window.open(
                    url, 'popUpWindow1', 'height=250,width=234,left=0,top=0,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no')
            }

            function a2(url) { 
popupWindow2 = window.open(
                    url, 'popUpWindow2', 'height=250,width=234,left=0,top=0,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no')
            }

            function a3(url) { 
popupWindow3 = window.open(
                    url, 'popUpWindow3', 'height=308,width=299,left=0,top=0,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no')
            }
            }
</script>

<a href="JavaScript:a1('images/focus_img1.html');">focus 1</a>
<a href="JavaScript:a2('images/focus_img2.html');">focus 2</a>
<a href="JavaScript:a3('images/focus_img3.html');">focus 3</a>
```

These links will be opened in separate windows

Comment: Isn't there a scalable solution. hard coding a function for each link is not good for long run

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a long time since the question was asked, but i'll answer because I found nothing on the web that clearly answer the question. An easy way is to use a link with an click() event.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[data-popup]', function(e) {
  var date = new Date();
  var mSec = date.getTime();
  my_window = window.open($(this).attr('href'), "Popup"+mSec, "top=0,left=0,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no, height=600, width=800");
  e.preventDefault();
  my_window.focus();
});
```

using the date.getTime() (It is impossible to have any return value repeated  since it's the amount of seconds since 1970 january 1st...) makes each new popup window with a new name :)

Answer (score -1):

The following code will open the number of popups as you want

```
<html> 
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function TohokuImgPopup(url) {
window.open(url,"windowName","windowFeatures")
window.open(url,"DifferentWindowName","windowFeatures")// different name for each popup
// create windows as much as you want to create
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Open Windows" onclick="TohokuImgPopup()">
</form>
</body>
```

you need to make sure that each window name is different, otherwise the last popup will overwrite it's previous popup. As a result you will end up with a single popup